# XPages 8.5.3 Calendar

Tags: calendar, xpages

I am using XPages 8.5.3 without the extension library. I would like to add a calendar view to an XPages. Is there any way of doing this without using the XPages Calendar from OpenNTF?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "not easily".

The long answer depends on the layout you want to display (day, week, month, time components etc). Once you have that, you will create a calendar view in Designer, use getAllEntriesByKey() using a date range, and you have your data. Then you need to construct your UI using nested repeat controls to display the "boxes" for each date / time, adding the content to display (ensuring if you have too much it doesn't distort the layout), test it under all circumstances (months have different numbers of days, not forgetting leap years). As the person who wrote that chapter of XPages Extension Library, documenting the components involved covered a number of pages - it's not a simple piece of code!

I've been involved with XPages since 8.5.0, I'm not aware of any blog posts showing how to do it prior to Extension Library.

If this is critical functionality for the application, I would strongly recommend deploying XPages Extension Library or Upgrade Pack 1 (if it's still available). If that's not an option, I would strongly recommend just presenting the content as a list rather than a calendar layout.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get the Extension Library installed

Answer (score 1):

Paul is right: not easy.

A second path: pick a pure Javascript client side calendar implementation ([like this one](https://fullcalendar.io/)) and feed it through a Json stream. Since you are on "vintage Domino", instead of using the Rest control, you need to use an [XAgent](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2008/12/xagents-web-agents-xpages-style.html).

Let us know what worked out for you

Comment: Thanks. The Calendar should work in both the Lotus Notes client and in web clients. Will jQuery / Javascript work in the Lotus Notes client?

Comment: There's only one way to find out: slap it on a page and try. You will run with a rather old Mozilla rendering engine, so it is anybody's guess. A static example should give you the insight